# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I have been using java 1.5 in the Linux environment.

I use HTTP post method to send the XML request to the supplier and get the XML response from the supplier. Connecting URL is HTTPS. While I am connecting to them, getting the following error.

> Error @ AUTOEUROPE_Login - init ()javax.net.ssl.SSLException:
>   Unsupported record version Unknown-48.51

This is my code.

```
InputStream  mIstr   =  null;
OutputStream mOstr   =  null;    
URL mUrl             =  new URL(this.mURL);

HttpURLConnection mUConn = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();   
mUConn.setUseCaches(false);

mUConn.setDoInput(true);
mUConn.setDoOutput(true);
mUConn.setRequestMethod("POST");

mUConn.connect();
mOstr = mUConn.getOutputStream();
mOstr.write(mRequest.getBytes());
mIstr = mUConn.getInputStream();

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(mIstr); 
String tempStr = "";
while((tempStr = dis.readLine())!=null){
responseBfr.append(tempStr); 
}
```

**Sample forums**
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK32916
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1532173

I have delete old SSL certificate and installed it again and issue is same. Checked in the google but couldn't identified the solution for this.

Comment: Where is this certificate you are using coming from? Maybe the certificate is corrupted? Try using OpenSSL to verify that it is valid?

Comment: I resolved this problem. Actually It was not my issue. issue with the certificate provider with validating SSL URL. They have fixed it. Anyway thanks for the support.